# Highcharts: Credits on multiple lines

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want to display the source of graphic data in the credits of various Highcharts charts. However the string for this source can at times be quite long and will not fit on a single line. I could manually set the y value of the credits and the spacingBottom of the chart, but since I have over 50 graphics with different sources/credits (some that will fit on a single line, some that won't), is there a way to set default options that would automatically cover all possibilities?

A simple Fiddle here that shows that extra text is cut off: http://jsfiddle.net/kFskZ/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's what do you want.

Use `Highcharts.setOptions`.

```
var options = {
    credits: {
        text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam suscipit nulla a elit porta vitae condimentum eros vehicula. Nam rhoncus mattis turpis quis rhoncus. Fusce pulvinar faucibus odio, at ultricies diam dignissim et. Donec at nibh est, quis posuere purus.',
    style: {
        width: 300
    },
        position: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 10
        }
    }    
};

Highcharts.setOptions(options);
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kFskZ/2/)

**Update**:
There are many possibilities.
You can change `legend` position and increase your legend `width`. [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kFskZ/7/)

Comment: No, what I want is the "Lorem ipsum" text in the example to be displayed in its entirety. Right now only a single line is displayed "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam". I would like the solution to be flexible so that depending on the length of the credits text, the size of the graph area grows to show  the complete credits string.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with SVGs as there is no way to auto text wrap within SVG - you need to manually calculate the lines you want and then add multiple 'tspan' elements within your 'text' element for each respective line. I would submit an issue to the HighCharts team to see if they could address this in a future release.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using the credits 'position' option and by putting an html break tag to create line breaks. I had to keep messing with position until all my text was visible as desired. See documentation at
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/design-and-style

```
credits: {
    text: 'Powered by ACIS<br/>Western Regional Climate Center',
    href: 'http://wrcc.dri.edu',
    position: {
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        x: -20,
        y: -20
    }
},
```